# Naming intersection points of a grid

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to automatically give names to all intersection points of a grid, so that I can draw from a specific intersection to another.

In my example, I manually gave names to the coordinates of some intersection points to illustrate my point.

So I want to draw from intersection a to intersection b, not from position (1,1) to (2,2); and from intersection x to intersection z, not from position (3,3) to (4,3)

Can this be done without using an extra package, because I can not install new packages (on my workplace computer) for security reasons.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{N}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=.5cm,color=gray] (0,0) grid (8,8);
\draw<2->[ultra thick, green, -latex] (1,1) -- (2,2);
\draw[blue!40!black, thick, fill=blue!40!white, opacity=.5] (3,3) circle (.2cm) node (c){};
\draw<3->[ultra thick, red, -latex] (c.center) -- (4,3);
\node at (1,1)(a){a};
\node at (2,2)(b){b};
\node at (3,3)(x){x};
\node at (4,3)(z){z};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @marmot Thank you for your comment, but I do not want to change the x/y scaling. This is an MWE not the whole drawing. There are other drawings in other intersections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second try at it. I hope I understood you: what I am doing here is building the grid by hand, and automatically naming the intersections. You can change the grid parameters (x and y step) and let everything else untouched; the intersections are called `g-<column>-<row>`.

Another possibility is to use a TikZ `matrix of nodes` for this.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{N}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            %  \draw[step=.5cm,color=gray] (0,0) grid (8,8);
            \def\mystepx{0.8cm}
            \def\mystepy{0.5cm}
            \foreach  \x in {0,...,8} {
                % draw rows and columns
                \draw [red] (\x*\mystepx, 0) -- (\x*\mystepx,8*\mystepy);
                \draw [blue] (0,\x*\mystepy) -- (8*\mystepx,\x*\mystepy);
                \foreach \y in {0,...,8} {
                        \coordinate (g-\x-\y) at (\x*\mystepx,\y*\mystepy);
                    }
                }
            %
            \node at (g-1-1){a};
            \node at (g-2-2){b};
            \node at (g-3-3){x};
            \node at (g-4-3){z};
            \draw<2->[ultra thick, green, -latex] (g-1-1) -- (g-2-2);
            \draw[blue!40!black, thick, fill=blue!40!white, opacity=.5] (g-3-3) circle (.2cm) node (c){};
            \draw<3->[ultra thick, red, -latex] (c.center) -- (g-4-3);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: result of above code]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What you suggested is what I used in my example. As the title of my question says, my point is to name the intersection points of the grid and use them as nodes, not to use the absolute coordinates.

Comment: I edited my post to clarify my point and explain what I need.

Comment: Trying again...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am sorry for the delay of my comment

Answer (score 4):

If you remove the units from the steps and do, say, `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=2cm]` this will increase the step of the grid while keeping the same intersections (or lattice nodes) connected.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{N}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=2cm]
\draw[step=.5,color=gray] (0,0) grid (5,4);
\draw<2->[ultra thick, green, -latex] (1,1) -- (2,2);
\draw[blue!40!black, thick, fill=blue!40!white, opacity=.5] (3,3) circle (.2cm) node (c){};
\draw<3->[ultra thick, red, -latex] (c.center) -- (4,3);
\node at (1,1){a};
\node at (2,2){b};
\node at (3,3){x};
\node at (4,3){z};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of `to path` style that name all intersections of a grid. When you set `named grid=test` the intersections will be named as `test-1-1`, `test-1-2`, ... and so on.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
% The x-step and the y-step lengths
\newlength{\dx}\setlength{\dx}{1cm}
\newlength{\dy}\setlength{\dy}{1cm}
% recover the steps
\makeatletter
\let\pgf@pathgrid@original\pgf@pathgrid
\def\pgf@pathgrid[#1]#2#3{%
  \pgfset{#1}%
  \pgfmathsetlength\dx{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/stepx}}%
  \global\dx=\dx
  \pgfmathsetlength\dy{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/stepy}}%
  \global\dy=\dy
  \pgf@pathgrid@original[#1]{#2}{#3}
}
\makeatother
% define the `named grid` style
\tikzset{
  named grid/.style={
    to path={
      (\tikztostart) grid (\tikztotarget)
      let \p1=(\tikztostart), \p2=(\tikztotarget),
      \n1={min(\x1,\x2)},\n2={max(\x1,\x2)},
      \n3={ceil(\n1/\dx)},\n4={\n3+1},\n5={int(\n2/\dx)},
      \n6={min(\y1,\y2)},\n7={max(\y1,\y2)},
      \n8={ceil(\n6/\dy)},\n9={\n8+1},\n{10}={int(\n7/\dy)}
      in
      foreach[count=\nx from 0] \x in {\n3,\n4,...,\n5}{
        foreach[count=\ny from 0] \y in {\n8,\n9,...,\n{10}}{
          (\x*\dx,\y*\dy) coordinate (#1-\nx-\ny) % <- name the intersections
        }
      }
    }
  },
  named grid/.default=grid
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[rotate=35,xstep=.7,ystep=.35] (-.5,-1.5) to[named grid=test] (3.5,1.5)
      (test-1-1) edge[-latex,red,thick] (test-5-7)
      (test-0-0) circle(3pt) (test-5-8) circle(3pt);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Notes :**

- This code is note very stable : it doesn't work well with non linear transforms.
- In a strange way, the most difficult part for me was to recover the steps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you said it is not very stable.